# Symbolic solution of equation system using Sympy with trivial solutions depending on symbols

Tags: python, linear-algebra, sympy, equation

I have an equation system like the following:

[image]

For this specific system, I know that a nontrivial solution(s) only exists if p1 == p2, which is

[image].

However, how can I determine this in the general case using Sympy?

For this example, my implementation is as follows:

```
from sympy import Matrix, symbols, pprint, lcm, latex
from sympy.solvers import solve_linear_system

top_matrix = Matrix.zeros(8,7)
p1 = symbols("p1")
p2 = symbols("p2")

top_matrix[0,0] = 1
top_matrix[0,1] = -1

top_matrix[1,1] = (1-p1)
top_matrix[1,2] = -1

top_matrix[2,2] = 1
top_matrix[2,4] = p2-1

top_matrix[3,1] = p1
top_matrix[3,3] = -1

top_matrix[4,3] = 1
top_matrix[4,4] = -p2

top_matrix[5,4] = 1
top_matrix[5,5] = -1

top_matrix[6,1] = -1
top_matrix[6,6] = 1

top_matrix[7,4] = -1
top_matrix[7,6] = 1

pprint(top_matrix)
vars = symbols("a1, a2, a3, a4, a5, a6, a7, a8")
print solve_linear_system(top_matrix, *vars)
```

The result is

```
None
```

If I set

```
p2 = p1
```

the result is

```
{a1: -1, a5: -1, a2: -1, a6: -1, a3: p1 - 1, a4: -p1}
```

Is there some way to discover this *requirement* automatically?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your example code, [`solve_linear_system`](http://docs.sympy.org/dev/modules/solvers/solvers.html) expects an augmented system, i.e., if the right hand side is zero, the matrix should be declared as `Matrix.zeros(8,8)`. With this modification, your code yields

```
{a3: 0, a1: 0, a5: 0, a7: 0, a6: 0, a2: 0, a4: 0}
```

which is indeed a solution, although not the interesting one...

To remedy this, one can explicitly request that one component of the solution should be normalized to, say, 1. So if you do something like the following:

```
from sympy import Matrix, symbols, pprint, lcm, latex, solve

top_matrix = Matrix.zeros(8,7)
p1,p2 = symbols("p1, p2")

top_matrix[0,0] = 1
top_matrix[0,1] = -1

top_matrix[1,1] = (1-p1)
top_matrix[1,2] = -1

top_matrix[2,2] = 1
top_matrix[2,4] = p2-1

top_matrix[3,1] = p1
top_matrix[3,3] = -1

top_matrix[4,3] = 1
top_matrix[4,4] = -p2

top_matrix[5,4] = 1
top_matrix[5,5] = -1

top_matrix[6,1] = -1
top_matrix[6,6] = -1

top_matrix[7,4] = 1
top_matrix[7,6] = 1

pprint(top_matrix)

a1,a2,a3,a4,a5,a6,a7 = list(symbols("a1, a2, a3, a4, a5, a6, a7"))

B = Matrix([[1],[a2],[a3],[a4],[a5],[a6],[a7]])

C = top_matrix * B

print(solve(C, (a2,a3,a4,a5,a6,a7,p1,p2)))
```

and solve for the remaining variables as well as the parameters `p1,p2`, the result is:

```
[{a2: 1, a7: -1, a4: p2, a6: 1, a5: 1, p1: p2, a3: -p2 + 1}]
```

which is indeed the desired solution.

Answer (score 4):

It appears that sympy treats `p1` and `p2` as non-equal, which means that

```
top_matrix.nullspace()
```

> `[]`

that is, the homogeous system with matrix coefficients `top_matrix` has no non-trivial solution.

You have two options, here. The first is to treat the homogeneous system as having unknown variables both the elements of vector `b` *and* `p2`, treating `p1` as a fixed parameter.

```
b = sp.Matrix(sp.symbols('b1:8')) #import sympy as sp
sp.solve(top_matrix*b, (*b,p2))
```

> ```
> [{b1: 0, b2: 0, b3: 0, b4: 0, b5: 0, b6: 0, b7: 0}, 
>  {b1: b7, b2: b7, b3: b7*(-p1 + 1), b4: b7*p1, b5: b7, b6: b7, p2: p1}]
> ```

Note that the system has two solutions. The trivial one (with arbitrary `p2`), and a non-trivial one, where it holds `p2==p1` (with arbitrary `b7`).

The second option is to realize that the system `A*b=0` has a non-trivial solution if the system `A.T*A*b=0` has a non-trivial solution. The latter is possible if the determinant of `A.T*A` is zero. The determinant of `A.T*A` equals

```
(top_matrix.T * top_matrix).det().factor()
```

> `6*(p1 - p2)**2`

immediately revealing that it must hold `p1==p2` in order to have a non-trivial solution.